# Why in SDWebImage "strong reference to UIImageView might cause a crash in the nested block"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I'm using an old version of SDWebImage but received a crash as below:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019671bbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                               0x0000000189932eac -[UIView(Rendering) contentMode] + 316
2   UIKit                               0x00000001899320e0 -[UIImageView _canDrawContent] + 144
3   UIKit                               0x0000000189932bac -[UIImageView _updateState] + 36
4   UIKit                               0x0000000189932b6c +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 88
5   UIKit                               0x0000000189c6b340 -[UIImageView _updateImageViewForOldImage:newImage:] + 452
6   UIKit                               0x0000000189932590 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 320
7   xxxx                                0x0000000100927adc __85-[UIImageView(WebCache) setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:progress:completed:]_block_invoke + 100
```

The block where the crash happened is:

```
        __weak UIImageView *wself = self;
    id<SDWebImageOperation> operation = [SDWebImageManager.sharedManager downloadWithURL:url options:options progress:progressBlock completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
                                         {
                                             __strong UIImageView *sself = wself;
                                             if (!sself) return;
                                             if (image)
                                             {
                                                 sself.image = image;
                                                 [sself setNeedsDisplay];
                                                 [sself setNeedsLayout];
                                             }
                                             if (completedBlock && finished)
                                             {
                                                 completedBlock(image, error, cacheType);
                                             }
                                         }];
```

Then I found a fix of SDWebImage, the commit comment is:

> Removed strong reference to UIImageView which was causing a crash in the nested block

Here is the [commit](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/commit/63d60d982601a3377fc0f3b8a15b3e7ea3f3bf08). The only change was removing the strong reference of the `UIImageView` in the block.

[image: The commit]

Use strong reference in the block to keep the consistence is widely used, but why SDWebImage had this change. Why this might cause a crash? If `UIImageView` would cause a crash, what else would?

Comment: My guess would be that the IV was removed from the view hierarchy, or was in some other way put into a state where it couldn't draw the image without crashing.  Removing the strong reference prevents the IV from being live after it has gotten into this invalid state.

Comment: @Avi Sounds reasonable. But still want a exactly explanation, if UIImageView has this kind of issue, what about others?

Comment: What's the exception message, is it auto-layout related?

Comment: @WainThe exception type is SIGSEGV. Exception codes is: SEGV_MAPERR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that fix would work around is a race condition during view removal and/or destruction where internal rendering buffers are being deallocated but the retain can be applied in time to prevent deallocation. Then if something triggers writing to those now-vanished buffers poof you get that segmentation error.

In theory this problem could be encountered anywhere that raw pointers are accessed directly and their destruction is not sufficiently guarded. In practice UIKit-level code isn't likely to run into it anywhere other than UIImage-based APIs, and I'd imagine it would be a fairly esoteric race condition that being careful to cancel all asynchronous updates before view teardown began should eliminate totally; which you should be doing to avoid unnecessary work anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we should be carefully to use strong reference for UIImage-based APIs.